# Pushing array as an item to another array - not creating multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array, `@allinfogoals` and I want to make this a multidimensional array. In attempt to accomplish this, I'm trying to push an array as an item like so:

```perl
push @allinfogoals, ($tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam);
```

Where those items in the array parenthesis are all individual strings I have beforehand. However, if I reference `$allinfogoals[0]`, I get the value of `$tempcomponents[0]` and if I try `$allinfogoals[0][0]` I get:

```
Can't use string ("val of $tempcomponents[0]") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

How can I add these arrays to `@allinfogoals` to make it a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the parens in

```
push @allinfogoals, ($tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam);
```

do nothing at all. It's just a weird way of writing

```
push(@allinfogoals, $tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam);
```

Parens change precedence; they don't create list or arrays.

---

Now on to your question. There's no such thing as a 2d array in Perl, and arrays can only hold scalars. The solution is to create an array of references to other arrays. That's why

```
$allinfogoals[0][0]
```

is short for

```
$allinfogoals[0]->[0]
   aka
${ $allinfogoals[0] }[0]
```

As such, you need to store your values in an array and put a reference to that array in the top-level array.

```
my @tmp = ( @tempcomponents[0,1], $singlehometeam );
push @allinfogoals, \@tmp;
```

But Perl provides an operator that simplifies that for you.

```
push @allinfogoals, [ @tempcomponents[0,1], $singlehometeam ];
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure why this works, but it does...

```
push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam));
```

Needed to create an iterator, `$i` to do this.

---

According to @ikegami, what follows is the reason.

That only works if `$allinfogoals[$i]` isn't defined, when it's a weird way of writing

```
@{$allinfogoals[$i]} = ( $tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam );
```

which utilises autovivification to do the equivalent of

```
$allinfogoals[$i] = [ $tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam ];
```

which can be achieved without `$i` using

```
push @allinfogoals, [ $tempcomponents[0], $tempcomponents[1], $singlehometeam ];
```

This last snippet is explained in detail in my answer.